# Dynamic tree load on calling a JSON

Tags: json, tree

I have a JSON that returns the top tree node and children. Then whenever I click the children it retrieves the grandchildren and other multilevels obtained from another JSON.
Is there any way to help to build this in a tree? Intially I would like to show the parent node and children node in a tree and then subsequently on click of children the tree should drill down to show other sub nodes.

This is a common scenario. Is there any easily available tools to build the tree ??

Thank you

Comment: Not that I am aware but which language/technology are you thinking of using for that?

Answer (score 2):

There are many JavaScript tree widgets out there, and any good one will do dynamic loading.

Here's a randomly-selected one, which happens to be from the popular YUI library:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/

By the way, to help clarify the wording of your question:

- The "top tree node" is usually referred to as the "root".
- "a JSON" is more accurately referred to as a "an XHR request that returns JSON".  Do a Google search for "XHR request" or "AJAX request" to find out more. Basically the async data fetch is an XmlHttpRequest, and JSON is the data format of the response.
- Rather than saying "build the tree", it's clearer to say "render the tree". "Build the tree" could refer to the process of constructing the tree data or rendering that tree data, so is ambiguous. The former usage is actually more common, whereas here you mean the latter.

**Update:**

More examples:

- [jqTree](http://mbraak.github.com/jqTree)
- [jqxTree](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtree/index.htm#demos/jqxtree/ajaxloading.htm)
- [dynaTree](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/)
- [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/)
- [Dojo tree](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/Tree.html)

  - [lazy load demo](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.0.2/dojo-release-1.0.2/dojox/data/demos/demo_LazyLoad.html)
- [ExtJS tree](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.tree.TreePanel)
- [Google Closure Tree](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_ui_tree_TreeControl.html)

Comment: Don't you mean "an AJAX request"? JSON is the data data returned by the request.

Comment: @Barmar Yep, that is clearer wording. Upvoted, updated. Thanks--

Answer (score 0):

A standalone HTML page with JS and CSS embedded may be found [here](https://github.com/Leedehai/expandable-tree-list), no third-party libraries required.